# Specify location of _includes in Jekyll _config.yml

Tags: templates, build, jekyll

I might be missing something here, but I cannot find out how to specify the location of the _includes directory that Jekyll should use in the build process.

According to the [Jekyll configuration docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/), you can specify the directory of the _plugins and _layouts directories, but nowhere does it say you can specify the _includes directory.

Here is a snippet from the [config docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) showing how to specify _layout and _plugins:

```
source:      .
destination: ./_site
plugins:     ./_plugins
layouts:     ./_layouts
include:     ['.htaccess']
exclude:     []
```

So am I missing something? Or can you not specify the location of _includes?

Comment: i just removed those tags

Answer (score 2):

I did forget to check this very important Jekyll docs [templates page.](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/)

> Jekyll expects all include files to be placed in an _includes
>   directory at the root of your source directory.

Therefore, that is the reason why there is no way to specify the location of the _includes directory.